# Too few parameters Expected 1, recordset issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having a problem getting a recordset to run from a query I created in an MS Access 2010 database. here is t he code I want to run:

```
Private Sub Command192_Click()
Dim recs As String
Dim param As Integer
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("UnitRec_Qry", dbOpenDynaset)

With rs
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst

While Not .EOF

recs = recs & vbNewLine & !Spara & " - " & !Rec
.MoveNext

Wend

End With


MsgBox (recs)
End Sub
```

What this should output is a message box with a number of records from the query in a list. I do this so I can gather this and a number of other records into a text file for copying and pasting into a separate system. At the moment, I'm running this code so I can place it all into a string variable.

My problem is that I'm getting the dreaded "Too Few parameters expected 1" error.

The query works, I've saved it into the database and tested it and I get the expected results.

I tried running the recordset with SQL:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT UnitRecommend_tbl.URecID, UnitRecommend_tbl.Spara," _
& " UnitRecommend_tbl.Rec, UnitRecommend_tbl.SvyID" _
& " FROM UnitRecommend_tbl" _
& " WHERE ((UnitRecommend_tbl.SvyID) = [Forms]![SurveyRegister_frm]![SurveyID])" _
& " ORDER BY UnitRecommend_tbl.Spara;", dbOpenDynaset)
```

I get the same error

I ran it again but removed the "WHERE" statement and the code ran just fine, but gave me every record in the table. Not what I wanted.

So, the fields are OK because the data runs. When I debug the text the parameter in the SQL does show up as the right parameter, in this case, the number 4 which is an integer.

So I'm at a loss here, I've searched through the other posts here and I have tried these possible solutions (unless I missed something).

I also tried using dbopensnapshot as well, still no joy. Wondering if I'm using the right code here now.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

A parameter like `[Forms]![SurveyRegister_frm]![SurveyID]` doesn't get evaluated automatically if you open a recordset in VBA.

Use this function:

```vb
Public Sub Eval_Params(QD As DAO.QueryDef)

On Error GoTo Eval_Params_Err

    Dim par As DAO.Parameter

    For Each par In QD.Parameters
        ' This is the key line: Eval "evaluates" the form field and gets the value
        par.Value = Eval(par.Name)
    Next par

Eval_Params_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

Eval_Params_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Runtime-Error " & Err.Number & " in Eval_Params"
    Resume Eval_Params_Exit

End Sub
```

with a QueryDef object like this:

```vb
Dim QD As QueryDef
Dim RS As Recordset

Set QD = DB.QueryDefs("UnitRec_Qry")
Call EVal_Params(QD)
Set RS = QD.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

Alternatively, you can run it with SQL in the VBA code by moving the parameter outside of the SQL string:

```vb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT UnitRecommend_tbl.URecID, UnitRecommend_tbl.Spara," _
& " UnitRecommend_tbl.Rec, UnitRecommend_tbl.SvyID" _
& " FROM UnitRecommend_tbl" _
& " WHERE ((UnitRecommend_tbl.SvyID) = " & [Forms]![SurveyRegister_frm]![SurveyID] & ")" & _
& " ORDER BY UnitRecommend_tbl.Spara;", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: OK, will give it a try.

Comment: Got an error. "Compile Error; a module is not a valid type". I saved the first code snippet as a module. I'm guessing I shouldn't have done that?

Comment: Yes, "Sub EVal_Params" should go into a standard module (new or existing). Which line is highlighted as error?

Comment: OK, so why the error? Just tried it in the form's code and got the same error. Maybe a referencing issue?

Comment: Perhaps you have a module called "Parameter" ? Try `Dim par As DAO.Parameter`

Comment: No on both counts. When the error come up, it highlights the line ` QD As QueryDef ` which is the DIM line

Comment: If SurveyID is a number you've generated in one of your tables, use Andre451's alternative approach. It's much simpler. Parameter queries are good to know, but don't have to be used for every query. Generally they should used anytime you are dealing with user supplied data, but in a case like this it's probably safe to go with the simpler solution.

Comment: Then use `QD As DAO.QueryDef` in all places.

Comment: The SurveyID is the Primary key, auto number, so yes it is a number. Dont know of Andre451's solution. an you link me to it? OOPS sorry, just saw the code...

Comment: it's the alternate suggestion he listed above..."Alternatively, you can run it with SQL in the VBA code by moving the parameter outside of the SQL string:"

Comment: Score! You guys are awesome. Thanks Andre451. I'e always been a little confused about getting those quotations right. Seems really onvoluted to me. Will keep this as a guide. Cheers

Comment: Cool. :) If you use "UnitRec_Qry" for something else than this recordset, I would still go with the parameter query and EVal_Params(), just so you don't have the same SQL twice in your database (in the query and in VBA).  P.S. if the question is solved, please accept the answer, so shows up as "answered".