# Error with Allen Browne's ELOOKUP: Too Few Parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been working on this for about an hour and can't get the function to run without errors. I am using Allen Browne's ELOOKUP function from [this](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-42.html) page.

Here is the code currently calling the public function:

```
Dim r As Double
Dim Q1 As Double
Dim i1 As Double
r = Me!txtRepeat
Q1 = Me!txtQty1
i1 = ELookup("dblIndex", "zhqry_ActiveGrid_3_Final", "dblRepeat = " & r & " AND dblQuantity <= " & Q1, "dblQuantity DESC")
```

I get the error "Too few parameters: Expected 1."

I have stepped through the code and was able to extract strSQL which was:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dblIndex 
FROM zhqry_ActiveGrid_3_Final 
WHERE dblRepeat = 12 AND dblQuantity <= 55 
ORDER BY dblQuantity DESC;
```

The actual error is thrown on this line of the ELOOKUP function:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenForwardOnly)
```

I have tried:

1. Encapsulating all field names in square brackets. Same error.
2. Adding single quotes around my criteria values. Same error.
3. Changed function line:`Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)` to `set db = CurrentDb`, Same error.
4. Changed `dbOpenForwardOnly` to `dbOpenSnapshot`. Same error.

I copied the strSQL value into Access's query builder and it ran fine so I know that I am building a valid string. I am using Access 2010.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmmm, have you tried `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)`

Comment: @GaryEvans Just tried that, same error.

Comment: Does `zhqry_ActiveGrid_3_Final` (or a subquery of it) have parameters like e.g. `Forms!myForm!myValue`? They are evaluated when opening the query in Access, but not when opening a recordset on it. -- See "Limitations of ELookup(): ... DLookup() can call the expression service to resolve an argument.."

Comment: @Andre ah I thought that restriction was only for 'strSQL'. Yes my stacked query has a form reference. I need to make an approximate match so dlookup isn't reliable. I'll see if I can rework my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Limitations of ELookup():
>
> DLookup() can call the expression service to resolve an argument such as:
> DLookup("Surname", "Clients", "ClientID = [Forms].[Form1].[ClientID]")

This also applies to a query that is used as `Domain` parameter - parameters like this are resolved automatically in Access queries, but not in a recordset, which `ELookup()` uses.

You could modify `ELookup()` to not open the recordset directly, but from a Querydef object. Then you can call `Eval_Params()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271) on the QD object to resolve the parameters.

Comment: I've never seen any real advantages of the different attempts for "improving" DLookup.