# Access: Running query with DAO.recordset that selects from another query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access form with a text field, and a subform. The text field is a parameter to a query named myQuery, and the subform shows the results of myQuery.

In VBA I want to access the first row of myQuery so I tried using `DAO.recordsets` like so:

```
dim query as string
dim rs as DAO.recordset
query = "select top 1 * from myQuery"
set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query)
```

I get an error saying "Too few parameters".

If I go to the create query tab, and run the SQL code "select top 1 * from myQuery" it works. I am guessing that when running queries via `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` that you can't treat another query as a table like you can with regular SQL.

Does anyone know how to select from another query using `OpenRecordset`?

Regards

Comment: Your saved query is referencing a control on your Form, so when you call your saved query it tries to evaluate `Forms!SomeForm!TextField` as a parameter instead of looking at the actual control itself. Do away with the saved query and put the full query text into your `query` string variable.

Comment: Thanks, with some tweaking I was able to get your approach to work.

Comment: Or if the query is complicated enough that you don't want to put the whole SQL into VBA, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a querydef and evaluate parameters before opening to a recordset. However, no specific `SELECT` expression can be used in this instance but whole query object. The `TOP 1` can be mirrored with selecting recordset values without looping (as it picks first).

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.querydef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("myQuery")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
rst.MoveFirst

Debug.Print rst.Fields(0), rst.Fields(1), rst.Fields(2), rst.Fields(3), rst.Fields(4)
```