# Copying the Access query into an Excel sheet using VBA is failing

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

One part of my VBA code copies the Access queries into an excel sheet

```
MyConn = Worksheets("eingaben").Range("B2").Value
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
  .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
  .Open MyConn
End With

For i = 0 To 14
'
SSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & marrSql(i) & "];"

Set cmdCommand = New ADODB.Command
Set cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cnn
With cmdCommand
    .CommandText = SSQL
End With

Debug.Print marrSql(i)
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
'rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open Source:=cmdCommand, CursorType:=AdForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

Workbooks("Cop.xls").Activate


Range(marrPlace(i)).CopyFromRecordset rst
'
Next
```

some of queries are copied successfully BUT for some of them I get the following error:

```
Run-Time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)': No Value given for one or more required parameters."
```

[image]

I checked already in all these queries which can not be copied the first column is empty. However, it should not be a problem?!

That is the Query of one of them:

```
SELECT [Formulare]![Auswahlmaske]![Monat] AS Datum_SU, IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="REPA","VAC",IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLU","LLD",[CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE])) AS Produit, Count(K1ltit31.IE_AFFAIRE) AS AnzahlvonIE_AFFAIRE, Sum(IIf([SOLDE_COMPTA]<0,[CRD],[SOLDE_COMPTA]+[CRD])) AS [ENCOURS TOTAL], K1ltit31.CODE_STATUT_COMPTA
FROM K1ltit31
GROUP BY [Formulare]![Auswahlmaske]![Monat], IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="REPA","VAC",IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLU","LLD",[CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE])), K1ltit31.CODE_STATUT_COMPTA
HAVING (((IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="REPA","VAC",IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLU","LLD",[CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE])))<>"SERA" And (IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="REPA","VAC",IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLU","LLD",[CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE])))<>"SERF") AND ((K1ltit31.CODE_STATUT_COMPTA)="ctx"))
ORDER BY IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="CAU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="3WSU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="REPA","VAC",IIf([CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLN" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="KMLU" Or [CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE]="RWLU","LLD",[CATEGORIE_AFFAIRE])) DESC;
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Please add the SQL of a query that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Formulare]![Auswahlmaske]![Monat] AS Datum_SU
```

A parameter like this is evaluated when opening the query in Access, but not when opening a recordset on it.

For DAO I have a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271

For ADODB you can probably build something similar.
Or use a public function that reads the value from the form, and call that in the query.

Something like

```
' This goes into a standard module (not class module)
Public Function GetAuswahlMonat() As Variant
    GetAuswahlMonat = Forms![Auswahlmaske]![Monat]
End Function
```

and then

```
SELECT Min(GetAuswahlMonat()) AS Datum_SU, ...
...
GROUP BY IIf( ...
```

(it's probably better using a aggregate function and not grouping)

Comment: I was dealing with your suggestion but I do not know how can I do "use a public function that reads the value from the form"! Could you please help me or just say how can I start?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `marrSql(i)` returns null or something not good enough. Once you get the error, click on "debug button" and check the value of marrSql(i).

Comment: That is not true! That was my first suspicion and it works well. The other point is, that it works for couple of them and dose not work for some

Comment: From the code I see you have one query in a loop. Which fails. The reason it fails is because the marrSql(i) should be giving something wrong.I mean, nothing else can fail in "SELECT * FROM marrSql(i)" .

Comment: Initially, it gives good values, but as the loop goes, it gives a wrong one.

Comment: look at second pic please

Comment: Is this table "K1ltit" existing? Probably you may try to remove the spaces of the name of the table and write "_" in stead and try again?

Comment: So, is the tbl existing? Can you try to rename it w/o the spaces?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124509/discussion-between-mania-and-vityata).