# OpenRecordset not recognisng query criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have developed an Access Database query which references an object on a form in order to dynamically filter the data. The criteria upon which the query is filtered is as follows:

```
[Forms]![frmMain]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![Frame64]
```

Where [frame64] is where the user chooses one of two options on a form.

Whilst this query runs fine in Access, I want to use this query in a piece of VBA code, but the problem is, when I try to open the record set, VBA won't allow me.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset    


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryMergeEzineCompleteMerges", dbOpenDynamic, dbSeeChanges)
```

Through my research, I have discovered that it is because VBA doesn't recognise the query criteria I have defined as it refers to a form.

Can anyone please show me how I can reference this recordset in VBA so that it filters by the criteria I have stipulated in the query itself?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too few parameters Expected 1, recordset issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118072/too-few-parameters-expected-1-recordset-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the Recordset through a [QueryDef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822070.aspx).

```
Sub Whatever()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryMergeEzineCompleteMerges")

   'add any parameters here
    With qdf
        .Parameters("[parameter1]").Value = value1
        .Parameters("[parameter2]").Value = value2
    End With

    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

    '...

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kostas, this makes sense to me now. I wasn't sure of the syntax, but you explained this beautifully. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This may sound pretty stupid but the easiest way to solve this is to create two constants for the dbOpenDynamic and dbSeeChanges values and set their values to the right integer values. You can of course also just type the relevant integer values in the OpenRecordset call.

Comment: This is not the issue here.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for this. I'm pretty new to VBA coding, so I'm afraid that your response means very little to me.

Could you bridge the gap and flesh out your explanation for me so I might have a better chance of understanding it?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is is that the integer values could change depending on what the is set in [Frame64]

Comment: @SteveO'Dea: The answer and explanation are in the link André provided.

Comment: Thanks folks, it looks like the threads are similar, although I like Kostas' solution below. Thanks for the input