# VBA Access: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know, there are lots of answers out there for this problem which should be trivial, but I did not find the right one. Here is my problem:
I open a record set with the following select statement:

```
SELECT twinecellar.produktnavn, twinecellar.land, 
 twinecellar.produkttype,  twinecellar.år, 
 twinecellar.antall, twinecellar.poeng, 
 twinecellar.Picture, twinecellar.KR, 
 twinecellar.Poengsum, twinecellar.Sum
FROM twinecellar
WHERE (((twinecellar.land)=forms!fmainview!list13) 
  And ((twinecellar.produkttype)=forms!fmainview!list15))
ORDER BY twinecellar.poeng;
```

In the immidiate window I see that list 13 contains "france" and list 15 contains "red"
When I create a new Query with this statement, it's working, however, on the rst.Open gsStrQuery I get this error. gsStrQuery contains the select string.

Here is the code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rst.ActiveConnection = conn
rst.Open gsStrQuery
```

Anybody out there with a good idea about this issue?

Comment: when you write in the immediate window `?gsStrQuery` what do you get?

Comment: Same cause as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271 - but that answer has a solution for DAO. You need to set the parameters.

Comment: Please show assignment of *gsStrQuery* in VBA which is crucial to your question.

Comment: writing ?gsStrQuery, I get

Comment: writing ?gsStrQuery, I get SELECT twinecellar.produktnavn, twinecellar.land, twinecellar.produkttype, twinecellar.år, twinecellar.antall, twinecellar.poeng, twinecellar.Picture, twinecellar.KR, twinecellar.Poengsum, twinecellar.Sum
FROM twinecellar
WHERE (((twinecellar.produkttype)=[forms]![fmainview]![list15]))
ORDER BY twinecellar.land;

Answer (score 1):

When you build your SQL string, concatenate the "parameters" values into the string.

```
gsStrQuery = "SELECT twinecellar.produktnavn, twinecellar.land, " & _
                "twinecellar.produkttype,  twinecellar.år, " & _
                "twinecellar.antall, twinecellar.poeng, " & _
                "twinecellar.Picture, twinecellar.KR, " & _
                "twinecellar.Poengsum, twinecellar.Sum " & _
             "FROM twinecellar " & _
             "WHERE (((twinecellar.land)= '" & forms!fmainview!list13 & "') " & _
                "And ((twinecellar.produkttype)= '" & forms!fmainview!list15 & "')) " & _
             "ORDER BY twinecellar.poeng;"
```

That way your parameter values are hard coded into the string before you try to open the query.

(Also note: I added single quotes around your parameters to indicate they are strings.)

(Also also note: `& _` is a line continuation for VBA so your SQL string concatenates properly.  This allows you have a readable SQL code that's nicely indented.)

**________________________________**

There is also a way to use your current gsStrQuery and assign parameters values to the ADO recordset.  (But I find the above Replacement method much easier to read when going back to review the code.  The only drawback is you have to rebuild your SQL string each time your parameters change.  But that overhead is minimal for non complicated queries.)

However, if you really want to use ADO parameters, you can find a useful description [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181734/how-to-invoke-a-parameterized-ado-query-using-vba-c-java)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Abraxascarab, I am impressed! About your efforts and about your proposal. I posted your statement into my program, and it works. Thank you so much! Now I will dig into the details and try to learn why my own select statement, which was created by the Access query tool, did not work in this specific situation while yours work. You must be a genius!

Comment: Now I have investigated a bit. I do not get the error anymore, but I do not get any records back since the single quotes make forms!fmainview!list13 to a string, missing the content of the field. Do you have any further idea?

Comment: My point is, I can't hard code the parameters, because they come from choices I make in list boxes, like list13. I suppose it is possible to have fields as parameters, and not only hard coded strings?

Comment: @miwi The hard coded SQL should be possible (it works for me).  However, since you've clarified you are using List Boxes it may be a problem of which column you have "bound" in the List Box "property sheet".  Plus you need to make sure a value is "Selected" in both List Boxes before you run the query.  Check the value of gsStrQuery after it is built to verify you see  'france' and 'red' in the correct places.  If you can post the contents of gsStrQuery here in the comments, I can help you track down the problem.