# Too Few Parameters: Expected 1 - MSAcces Error 3061

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm getting the error 3061 in Access (VBA). Can you help me out? It looks to me like I wrote the select correctly. I know this question has been asked many times here, but I've tried out almost all the answer given but I couldn't resolve my problem. That's why I'm asking for help.

```
Private Sub cmdPLCompleto_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdPLCompleto_Click_Err

    Dim d As DAO.Database
    Dim r As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL2 As String

    Set d = CurrentDb()


        strSQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT qryPLCARTASCompleto.ZDR FROM qryPLCARTASCompleto"

    Set r = d.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)

     If r.EOF Then
        MsgBox "The Recordset is empty."
    End If
```

UPDATE

Here it's the SQL from `qryPLCARTASCompleto`:

```
SELECT PLCARTAS.*, Mid([ICP ID],3,4) AS ZDR
FROM PLCARTAS
WHERE (((PLCARTAS.FECHA)=[Forms]![frmCartas]![txtFecha]));
```

Comment: Please add the full SQL of qryPLCARTASCompleto to your question.

Comment: Already added it @Andre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too few parameters Expected 1, recordset issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118072/too-few-parameters-expected-1-recordset-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Either ZDR isn't a field name, or your query refers to a field on a form.

If the last, you must specify that parameter before opening the recordset.

For example:

```
Dim d As DAO.Database
Dim q As DAO.Querydef
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL2 As String

strSQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT ZDR FROM qryPLCARTASCompleto"    

Set d = CurrentDb
Set q = d.Querydefs("", strSQL2)
q.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![frmCartas]![txtFecha]    

Set r = q.OpenRecordset()

If r.EOF Then
    MsgBox "The Recordset is empty."
End If
```

Comment: ZDR is a column name from the query. I tried running `SELECT DISTINCT qryPLCARTASCompleto.ZDR FROM qryPLCARTASCompleto` and it worked.

Comment: Hey! @Gustav I'm getting the "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

" after running the solution you gave me with `d.Querydefs`hightlighted. Any idea why it's happing?

Comment: No. Double-check with @Andre 's link.