# Sending Email from MS Access Query with Parameters - Visual Basic

Tags: ms-access, vba

3061 Error, Too Few Parameters, 2 Expected.

Chain of queries - earliest query at beginning contains "[Enter Area:]" (AREA field in LOCALITY table) and "Enter Year" (e.g. 2015-16) (YEAR field in DATA table) leading to final query containing email addresses.

Want onClick button event to send email but suspect it's not picking up earlier two parameters hence 3061 error - any advice gratefully received.

```vb
Private Sub Command566_Click()
    'Opens the current access database
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Set db = CurrentDb
     Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
     Dim EmailAdd As String
     'Mail Message MM
     Dim MM As String
     Dim qrySQL As String

     Set db = CurrentDb   

     'Creates the SQL string - query contains just email addresses
      qrySQL = "SELECT QRY_N_M109.EMAIL FROM QRY_N_M109;"

     'creates a recordset (table) based on the sql Statement above
      Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(qrySQL, dbOpenDynaset)


      Do Until RS.EOF
          'creates the email string by reading the email from each record
          EmailAdd = EmailAdd & " ; " & RS!EMAIL
          'move next record RS!EMAIL
          RS.MoveNext
      Loop

    'creates Email body in HTML Format

     MM = "Dear Delegates,"
     MM = MM & "Blah blah blah"

     'create new email
     Set olook = CreateObject("outlook.application")

     Set oMail = olook.createitem(0)
     'Set parameters
     With oMail
         .bcc = EmailAdd
         .htmlbody = MM
         .subject = "Our title here"
         .cc = "address@address.com"
         .display
     End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too few parameters Expected 1, recordset issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118072/too-few-parameters-expected-1-recordset-issue)

Comment: Read that post already Andre - seems to refer to MS Access Forms rather than MS Access Queries using ! syntax to call up reference to the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *SetParameter*:

```
' Creates the SQL string - query contains just email addresses.
qrySQL = "SELECT QRY_N_M109.EMAIL FROM QRY_N_M109;"

' Set parameter values.
DoCmd.SetParameter "[Enter Area:]", "'" & InputBox("Enter Area:") & "'"
DoCmd.SetParameter "[Enter Year:]", "" & InputBox("Enter Year:") & ""

' Creates a recordset (table) based on the sql Statement above.
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(qrySQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. Might try that.