# Error 3061 Too few parameters 1 expected

Tags: ms-access, vba

The below is my code.  A simple loop to go through records in a query (qryMasterImageFolders) and then call the sub fs.listImages...

However, I keep receiving the 3061 error and the below line is highlighted:

```
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

The query does contain records and I have checked the spelling - what am I missing?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryMasterImageFolders")

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

With rst
  Do Until .EOF

    fs.listImages DLookup("ImageFolder", "qryMasterImageFolders")

      .MoveNext
  Loop
End With

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too few parameters Expected 1, recordset issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118072/too-few-parameters-expected-1-recordset-issue)

Comment: Most probably your query references a form control.

Comment: No form control no

Comment: Then please add the full SQL of the query to your question.

Comment: ok, the query had the switch command in.  I created a table and pasted the file paths in, now I receive the error '3265 Item not found in this collection'

Comment: Then you have a missing or misspelled table or field name.

Comment: nope, checked that

Comment: If you don't show the query, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my code and it is now working:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ImageFolder FROM tmpImagePaths")

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True

    fs.listImages DLookup("ImageFolder", "qryMasterImageFolders")

        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should have done:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryMasterImageFolders")
```