# dbOpenDynaset - 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I have a query called 'qryAddressBook'. I want to be able to loop vertically through the records in a specific field called 'Client_Address' and display those records on a single row in a table 'tblClient'.

I have done this in the past with tables using "Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblAddressBook", dbOpenTable)" with no issues....

...and I followed the syntax showed from Access Database.OpenRecordset method (DAO): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao

I continue to get an error that says, 'Object variable or With block variable not set' and it highlights the following text from my code:

```
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("qrySpecificNCR", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Here is my total code:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAddressBook"

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim SeqNum As Integer

Set dbs = CurrentDb

SeqNum = 1

Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryAddressBook", dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rs.EOF

    Dim srtAddress As String
    srtAddress = rs.Fields("Client_Address").Value

    Dim strSQLAddress As String
    strSQLAddress = "UPDATE tblClient SET " & SeqNum & " = '" & srtAddress & "' WHERE Record = 1;"

        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLAddress 

        SeqNum = SeqNum + 1

rs.MoveNext

Loop
```

Comment: If this code is copied, rather than typed in, then there is a typo - you declare `dbs`, but use `dsb` to set it equal to the Database Object, before using `dbs` to open the recordset.

Comment: It's good practice to include an "Option Explicit" and then compile your code. This will prevent some errors that may be tough to spot.

Comment: Am I using "Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryAddressBook", dbOpenDynaset)" correctly?

Comment: Wayne, Can you explain how I turn "Option Explicit" on?

Comment: Set Option Explicit to include in header of new modules in VBE > Tools > Options > check Require Variable Declaration. Will have to manually add to existing modules.

Comment: It seems you've just edited the mistake from your question. Does the current code still cause the error?

Comment: Your "Set" statement is coded correctly.  To add the "Option Explicit", simply go to the top of your module and add that line (no quotes).  Then click on "Debug | Compile"
Did you have "Set dsb..." or "Set dbs..."??

Comment: I put "Option Explicit" (no quotes) at the top of my code and now I get an error that says, "Compile error: Invalid inside procedure" and it highlights the button on my sub called "Private Sub CmbAddress_Click()"

Comment: Go to your code window, then run the compile. An error will take you to a specific line of code which we would need to see. If you have declared something Private INSIDE your subroutine, then cut it out and move to be the first code in the module (after the Option Explicit and, if present, also after Option Compare Database.
If "dbs" was misspelled as "dsb" that will cause the exact error you had.

Comment: Yikes. This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Joel, can you elaborate? I'm very new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand the explicit part...but I found the error.

My qryAddressBook had the following line of code:

```
FROM qryGlobalAddress
WHERE (((qryAddress.Client) = [FORMS]![frmClientAddress]![CmbClientName]));
```

I was pushing a form parameter from a combo box. When I changed this to a specific client name such as:

```
FROM qryGlobalAddress
WHERE (qryAddress.Client) = 'Smith, John';
```

Then the Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryAddressBook", dbOpenDynaset) worked perfectly.

The problem now is I'll need to figure out a way to push a form parameter to the query. :(

Comment: Your update query is not clear. What column is being updated? Do you have columns named `[1], [2], ...` and want to set this `SeqNum` to client address? Also, update will change the same records for all loop iterations with condition `Record = 1`. Is there no `ClientID` in query? Please show full SQL in question post above.

Comment: See here for a way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271

Answer (score 0):

cancatenate the form combo value

"FROM qryGlobalAddress WHERE (((qryAddress.Client) = '" & [FORMS]![frmClientAddress]![CmbClientName] & "'));"