# Setting Parameters to VBA and SQL Query using DAO

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So I am using buttons to run a query which then pulls the selected emails into an email.
There is a singular function for this and then each button sends the corresponding query to act as the recordset

```
Sub EmailQuery(strQueryName As String)

'On Error GoTo Err_EmailRequery_Click

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strEmail As String

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open strQueryName, cn
    
    With rs
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst

        Do While Not .EOF
            strEmail = strEmail & .Fields("Email") & ";"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    strEmail = Left(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - 1)
    
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , , , strEmail, , , True, False
    
'Exit_EmailRequery_Click:
'
'    Exit Sub
'
'Err_EmailRequery_Click:
'
'    MsgBox Err.Description
'
'    Resume Exit_EmailRequery_Click

End Sub


Private Sub cmdActive_Click()

    EmailQuery ("qryActiveSuppliers")
    
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAllSuppliers_Click()
    
    EmailQuery ("qryAllSuppliers")

End Sub

Private Sub cmdArrangements_Click()
    
    EmailQuery ("qryAgreementEmail")

End Sub

Private Sub cmdInactive_Click()
    
    EmailQuery ("qryInactiveSuppliers")

End Sub
```

[Form where the buttons are located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1xKa.png)
All queries runs correctly just by clicking it in access and all bar the arrangements query run correctly. I took out the criteria from it's SQL statement to see if it would run and it did.
The criteria is matched against the combobox selection on the form.
Below is the SQL statement for the Arrangements button.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblSuppliers.SupplierName, Nz([BusinessEmail],[PersonalEmail]) AS Email
FROM ((tblSuppliers 
INNER JOIN tblSuppliersAgreements ON tblSuppliers.ID = tblSuppliersAgreements.SupplierID) 
INNER JOIN tblContacts ON tblSuppliers.ID = tblContacts.SupplierID)
WHERE ((tblSuppliersAgreements.AgreementID)=[Forms]![frmMainMenu]![cboAgreement]);
```

[This is the error I am getting when I try to click the button to run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cAeQ.png)

I think it may have something to do with the way I open the query in the rs.open line and I need to call the criteria not just in the SQL statement? Any help on this issue or a solution would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

So I have changed my code to this with DAO to see if that would fix the issue. I now get an error on the line `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQueryname)`
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaoQl.png)

I have left the previous way commented so if a solution is provided for that I can change back at any time.

```
Sub EmailQuery(strQueryName As String)

'On Error GoTo Err_EmailRequery_Click

'    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
'    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQueryName)

'    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
'    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    MsgBox strQueryName
    
'    rs.Open strQueryName, cn
    
    With rs
'    .MoveLast
'    .MoveFirst

        Do While Not .EOF
            strEmail = strEmail & .Fields("Email") & ";"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    strEmail = Left(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - 1)
    
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , , , strEmail, , , True, False
    
'Exit_EmailRequery_Click:
'
'    Exit Sub
'
'Err_EmailRequery_Click:
'
'    MsgBox Err.Description
'
'    Resume Exit_EmailRequery_Click

End Sub
```

**Edit 2**

Current code in main function

```
Sub EmailQuery(strQueryName As String)

'On Error GoTo Err_EmailQuery_Click

    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQueryName)

    MsgBox strQueryName
    
    With rs
'    .MoveLast
'    .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            strEmail = strEmail & .Fields("Email") & ";"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    strEmail = Left(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - 1)
    
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , , , strEmail, , , True, False
    
'Exit_EmailQuery_Click:
'
'    Exit Sub
'
'Err_EmailQuery_Click:
'
'    MsgBox Err.Description
'
'    Resume Exit_EmailQuery_Click

End Sub
```

Current SQL

```
PARAMETERS [PrmID] Long;
SELECT DISTINCT tblSuppliers.SupplierName, IIf( IsNull(BusinessEmail) , PersonalEmail, BusinessEmail) AS Email
FROM (tblSuppliers 
INNER JOIN tblSuppliersAgreements ON tblSuppliers.ID = tblSuppliersAgreements.SupplierID) 
INNER JOIN tblContacts ON tblSuppliers.ID = tblContacts.SupplierID
WHERE ((tblSuppliersAgreements.AgreementID)=[PrmID]);
```

I know there are probably issues with the way the SQL is done, being halfway parameterised or just done wrong.

[image: Error with code in edit 2]

Comment: just insert a msgbox strQueryName at the point before rs.Open, what do you get?

Comment: I believe you need to use `DAO` in order to be able to pass just the query name. In `ADO` you will probably need to supply a valid command, e.g. `"SELECT * FROM " & strQueryName`.

Comment: @tinazmu I get "qryAgreementEmail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with your attempts:

- **Named Objects**: Calling a saved query with ADO `Recordset.Open` which mostly expects SQL statements or command objects and not named objects. Hence, the reason for your first error. Instead, use [**`Conn.Execute`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection?view=sql-server-ver16) which prepends standard SQL syntax to named objects. Alternatively explicitly pass `SELECT * FROM` with query objects. This is not an issue for DAO recordsets (library specifically focused on the MS Access object model whereas ADO is generalized for *any* backend).
- **Parameters**: Using form control values in backend queries that do not see form values. Any query not run with `DoCmd` like `OpenQuery` (for select queries) or `RunSQL` (for action queries) does not recognize form controls. Hence, the reason for second error. Instead of `Forms!MyForm!MyControl`, use [ADO Command parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver16) or [DAO QueryDefs parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao).
  Search [my `[vba]` tag answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1422451+%5Bvba%5D+parameters) for countless ADO or DAO parameters solutions. See below for your use case:

  ```vb
  Sub EmailQuery(strQueryName As String)
  On Error GoTo Err_EmailQuery_Click
      Dim strEmail As String
      Dim db As DAO.Database
      Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
      Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

      Set db = CurrentDb
      Set qdef = db.QueryDefs(strQueryName)

      With qdef
          ' BIND PARAMETER
          .Parameters("PrmID") = [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![cboAgreement]
          ' OPEN RECORDSET
          Set rs = .OpenRecordset()
      End With

      '...loop and email...

  Exit_EmailQuery_Click:
      rs.Close
      Set rs = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
  Exit Sub

  Err_EmailQuery_Click:
      MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
      Resume Exit_EmailQuery_Click
  End Sub
  ```
- **Special Functions**: Running only MS Access GUI methods like `NZ` in backend queries that do not recognize such functions. You will run into this error if you resolve above two issues. Use `IIF` + `ISNULL`/`IS NULL`. Similarly, VBA user-defined functions will not be recognized.

Comment: Can you please expand on the DOA method?

Comment: Also would I add the parameters to the button or to the main function? Because the main function gets the query name based on which button is clicked.

Comment: For a generic function to evaluate parameters from forms see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271 @Andrew

Comment: Your second attempt is the DAO method. So simply set up QueryDef parameters in main function. In your edit, you need to bind the `PrmID` param in SQL to the form control value in VBA then call `QueryDef.OpenRecordset`. See doc links and my past answers with working examples.

Comment: I have edited with DAO example to match your use case.

Comment: I am now getting a compile error from this "Argument not optional" The line it has flagged is in the with qdef section `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset()`

Comment: Whoops. Remove `db` since we want `QueryDef.OoenRecordset`. See edit.